# How to change Game_Data folder in unity for windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project for windows platform in unity and I want to change the data folder name, Example:

If we make a project and name it "**TheGame**" after building, we will have:

- `D:\\...\\TheGame\\TheGame.exe`
- `D:\\...\\TheGame\\TheGame_Data\\`

And how can I rename "**TheGame_Data**" to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and I renamed the folder DATA in all caps. The game still ran fine for me. My Unity version is 5.3.5f1.

Although, I can't personally find any page that talks about changing this folders name you should check this link out.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html

I found someone trying to change the name to DATA here:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/321932/renaming-the-data-folder.html

The problem here though is after rebuilding the game, the folder gameName_Data will show up again. Since `Application.dataPath` is read only, I think you are stuck with renaming the folder after every build and deleting the old renamed folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to name it "data" and I did, but if you find something else about it, let me know.